# Yii Global Var Count

Tags: yii, frameworks, global

I need to have a variable ready but it is a count of a column and I have tried all ways and no result, want I need is this:

```
public $ibruto = "SELECT SUM(ingreso_bruto) as ibruto FROM zf_ingresos";
```

And i called in the view:

```
<?php echo $this->ibruto; ?>
```

But it prints "SELECT SUM(ingreso_bruto) as ibruto FROM zf_ingresos" .

Comment: "SELECT SUM(ingreso_bruto) as ibruto FROM zf_ingresos"; Do you think it will bring you result from database?

Comment: No no, is an idea of what I need

Comment: then please go through http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao this link

Comment: As ali`s answer is correct but you need to learn some basic features  of yii framework If you want to learn yii because these features will not let you free if you continue to work with yii

Comment: @RafayZiaMir Completely agree :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$ibruto` property just holds a SQL Command string and of course it has no result. In order to get the result you can use `Yii Query Builder`. Just create a method in your class like bellow:

```
public function getIbruto(){
    $cdb=Yii::app()->db;
    $result=$cdb->createCommand($this->ibruto)->queryColumn();
    //$result is an array, for example $result[0] holds your data
    return $result;
    //OR CVarDumper::dump($result,5678,true);
}
```

Now, You can get the data using `$this->getIbruto()`